# haveing bunch of errors after installing bluestacks

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, bluestacks

I`m stuck in bunch of errors...right after i finished my bluestacks installation and when i launched the application for first time i faced with this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JlF8.png)

and my system details are : GPU : ATI Radeon HD 4600 Series - intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 cpu 3.20 GHz - ram:2 GB ddr2 - and about 10 gig bytes available space in drive c:/ - OS:windows 7 32 bit - openGL ver 3.3 - DirectX 11 - valkan and open CL not sported
and i don`t know it is important or not...I have used application LeoMoon cpu-v and it just told me "Hardware Virtualization in NOT supported."
and i`m sure about my updated drivers.
guys beforehand i appreciate for ur attention and sorry for my poor english...

Comment: What errors are you getting and what are you trying to use bluestacks to do?

Comment: as u can see in the picture it is not a specific error and it just does not have a particular name...and i`m gonna use it to play some online apps

Comment: error : system.windows.markup.XamlParseException : cannot convert string 'Loaded' in attribute 'RoutedEvent' to object of type 'system.windows.RoutedEvent'. RoutedEventConverter cannot convert from system.string. Error at object 'System.Windows.EventTrigger' in markup file 'bluestacks;component/wpffiles/progressbar.xaml'.--->system,NotSupportedException: RoutedEventConverter cannot convert from system.string.
at system.componentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
at.....
at.....
at.....
---End of inner exception stack trace---